# The recent update of yammer has degraded the message API

Tags: yammer

None of the parsed, plain, and rich items in the body returned by the message API no longer indicate the correct original text.

```
async function yammerApiFetch(url, postData, extendRequest) {
    const yammerDefaultRequestHeader = {
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + options.accessToken,
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
    if (options.accessToken) {
        yammerDefaultRequestHeader.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + options.accessToken;
    } else {
        delete yammerDefaultRequestHeader.headers.authorization;
    }
    let req = $.extend(yammerDefaultRequestHeader, extendRequest);
    if (postData) {
        req.method = req.method || "POST";
        req.body = JSON.stringify(postData);
    }
    return (await fetch(url, req)).json();
}

bg.getMessage = async function (messageId) {
    return await yammerApiFetch(
        `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/${messageId}.json`);
};
```

If you write  in the text of the comment, you will make a tag   without escape.

Furthermore, if a string such as unknown.domain.com is included, an unusual tag such as   is added.

Comment: If I write &lt;tag /&gt; in the text of the comment, the API will make a tag &lt;tag&gt;&lt;/tag&gt; without escape.

Comment: unusual tag such as &lt;http:&gt;&lt;/http:&gt; is added.

Comment: I can not write tags even to stack overflow. terrible.

Comment: Recently, yammer became able to write a comment with HTML, and the logo changed. That's about when the bug started to appear.